# Deleting a folder on another thread causes webpage to not update?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, filesystemobject

I have a web app which displays a list of emails that need to be sent for the day. The user can select what emails to send, then click a button to generate them. When they click the Send button, a process gets started on another thread which generates the emails, then cleans up after itself by deleting a temp folder. Once the process is finished, the Repeater is rebound to update the User's view and remove the emails that have just been sent so they don't get sent again.

My problem is that when I delete the temp folder from my 2nd thread, the UI doesn't update with the new Repeater data. It updates correctly if I just delete the files in the folder instead of the folder itself, and it also updates correctly if I run the delete the folder on the original thread instead of the 2nd one.

New Thread code

```
Dim t as Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf EmailLetters))
t.Start()
```

Delete folder code

```
Dim fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.DeleteFolder(Server.MapPath(".") + "\tmpEmailFiles")
```

Why won't the UI update to show the new repeater values when I delete a folder on another thread?

**EDIT**

Here is some sample code that shows the problem. Sorry if its a bit messy, but I just needed something simple to help me identify the problem.

When you click the button, a thread gets started and a javascript load script starts executing which does a PostBack every 10 seconds. Each postback checks if the thread is complete and updates the Status label showing the result. If I delete a folder from within the background thread, the final update to the status label never occurs. If I remove the DeleteFolder call, it does.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Implements Interface="System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler" %>

<SCRIPT language="vb" runat="server">

  Sub Page_Load(Src As Object, e As EventArgs)

  End Sub

  Public Sub Test(src as Object, e as EventArgs)

    Dim t as Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf TestWorker))
    t.Start()

    Session("BackgroundThread") = t

  End Sub

  Public Sub TestWorker()

    ' 30 Second Delay
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)

    Dim root as String = Server.MapPath(".")
    Dim fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fs.FolderExists(root + "\Test") Then fs.CreateFolder(root + "\Test")
    fs.DeleteFolder(root + "\Test")

    ErrMsg.Text = "Start: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()

  End Sub

  Public Sub RaisePostBackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) _
    Implements IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent

    If Session("BackgroundThread") is Nothing Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim t as Thread = CType(Session("BackgroundThread"), Thread)
    If t.ThreadState = ThreadState.Stopped Then
      ErrMsg.Text = "Done: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() 
      Session("BackgroundThread") = Nothing
    Else
      ErrMsg.Text = "Processing: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + t.ThreadState.ToString()
    End If

  End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <SCRIPT language="javascript">
  //<!--

  function onLoad()
  {
    if(<%= IIF(Session("BackgroundThread") is Nothing, "false", "true") %>)
    {
      toggleLoading();
      setTimeout("<%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, "") %>", 10000);
    }
  }

  function toggleLoading(){
    document.getElementById('imgLoading').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout("document.images['imgLoading'].src='images/loading.gif'", 100); 
  }

  // -->
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY OnLoad="onLoad();">
<FORM runat="server">

  <ASP:Button runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="Test" onClientClick="javascript: toggleLoading();" />
  <ASP:Label runat="server" Id="ErrMsg" />
  <IMG id="imgLoading" src="images/loading.gif" style="display: none;" />

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Does it still show the data that has been deleted?  Is it caching it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the UI does not update to show any changes - It acts like the PostBack never occurred. In addition to the Repeater not updating to remove deleted items, there is also a status Label which should get updated and is not.

Comment: Is it caching the results of the file-system query?  If so, have you considered a `FileSystemWatcher` to invalidate the cache?

Comment: Why would that stop UI from updating? I updated my question with some sample code illustrating the issue. I'm updating a Label instead of a Repeater, but the result is the same.

Comment: Your sample works for me.  I get the "Done" message after 30 seconds.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I figured out my problem and posted it as an answer below. Turns out deleting a folder in the asp directory was causing the application to reset, which cleared all session variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my problem. Turns out deleting any folder in the ASP root folder will restart the application and reset all Session variables.

To get around that I added the following to my `Application_OnStart` method in `Global.asax`

```
Dim p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = GetType(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
Dim o As Object = p.GetValue(Nothing, Nothing)
Dim f As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = o.GetType.GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
Dim monitor As Object = f.GetValue(o)
Dim m As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = monitor.GetType.GetMethod("StopMonitoring", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
m.Invoke(monitor, New Object() {})
```

Comment: Ahar so the temp folder is inside the webfolder, well found on finding the problem and a solution.  It might be also worth having the temp folder outside of your webfolder to avoid the webapp from restarting when it doesn't have to?

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that this is a background thread on the server that is sending the emails finishes but the response has already been sent to the user.  When The user opens the page the background thread is started off, and the server returns with the response on the parent thread, the background thread is still running away on the server for sometime AFTER the response has already been sent

To achieve what you want you would need to have the page refreshing on a Javascript or some ajax to poll the server and keep check if this background thread has completed.  ie the background thread is started, and the user is told that emails are being proccessed, 2 seconds later the page is automatically refreshed and the user is still told emails are being processed.  Finally When all emails are sent the repeater is updated and automatic refresh is disabled

Comment: I do have that. The process sets a flag which causes a javascript script to run which polls the server until the background thread is completed. Once the background thread completes, the javascript code stops polling the server and the webpage SHOULD update. The problem is it does not update if I delete a folder from the background thread.

Comment: Oh apologies, your initial question didn't make that clear.  What kind of flag are you storing this in?  It sounds like it could be a locking/cross thread problem.

Comment: It's a Session variable. I can update my original question to show some full sample code.

Comment: Figured out my problem. Turns out deleting a folder in the asp directory resets all the session variables.